# why can't I assign a list of an object to an IList of the interface it implements

Tags: c#, covariance

```
public interface IRandom {}    
public class Random: IRandom {}
```

I can assign:

```
IRandom random = new Random();
```

but when I try this:

```
IList<IRandom> randomList = new List<Random>();
```

I get `cannot convert List<Random> to target type IList<IRandom>`

Can someone please explain why not?

Basically I was trying to have a list I could assign another list to which contain items that inherited from `IRandom`.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx